# If two computers are connected to the same router via LAN, can I share files through that LAN connectivity?

Tags: networking, router, lan

I have a router that has 2 ethernet ports, meaning I can connect two computers to it. Now once I do that, will I be able to share files through that LAN connectivity? Meaning, since both computers are deriving their internet from one source and they're both connected to that source via the same router. Can they also directly communicate with each other? Furthermore, will that also mean that the two computers can be used to play video games together via LAN?

This question may seem incredibly basic to someone who has advance understanding, but we all have to start somewhere, a response would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is one of these ethernet ports labeled as WAN by chance? It's hard to answer this question without knowing the type of router and the (physical) connections you set up to it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the setup and the configuration of the router.

If both computers qare on the same network then then can share files with each other. Internet access is not relevant here. This is the most likely configuration in your case, though you do not explicitly state that.

In graphics

```
[Computer 1]   [Computer 2]                  [router] -- router to internet 
     |              |                         |  |
     |              +-------------------------+  |
     |                                           | 
     +-------------------------------------------+
```

Note that I did not consider on of these two ports as the Internet facing port.
Which is fair if you have ADSL, cable or similar.

If the two computers are configured with different network settings then they cannot directly talk to each other. In that case you need a device called a router. (which you just happened to have). That device can be configured to route traffic from one LAN to another.

Disclaimer #1: I am not sure if you mean a router with the word 'router.  That word is often abused these days for what could be called 'multifunctional gadget' which potentially includes modem, firewall, switch, wireless access point, routing and whatever marketing comes up with.

Disclaimer #2. I also assumed that you have two ports, and no 1 port and one explicitly for WAN.

If any of these two is true then the easiest way to share files is either buy a cheap hub, or a second set of network card and link both computers via that.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance in this field but what I call a router is something that I connect the ethernet cable to and then back to my computer which gives me internet, I may be misusing the word but that's the device I have. What I intend to do is connect two computers to it, and I'm not sure if connecting two computers to it (since it has two ports of ethernet) will allow me to configure them to also directly communicate to each other (the two computers) without the need of a another device like a switch or a hub. Looking forward to your response.

Comment: Since both computers are connected to the same network, shouldn't I be able to configure them to directly communicate/transfer files etc?

Comment: @Shahzad Rahim - Yes you can configure them to directly communicate. They must both have IP addresses on the same subnet. Most SoHo routers run a DHCP server that will automatically do this for you, if not, you can manually set the computer IPs. The computers must support standard protocols such as file sharing, or other communication protocols.

Comment: @user10216038 Thank you for responding, I would really like to clarify/confirm that by "same network" I mean that the internet connection they're both receiving is from the same modem/router. Please confirm, would be much appreciated.

Comment: To explain Hennes message, if your device has only 2 ethernet ports, and it is a router, then one ethernet port is called WAN and the other is called LAN 1. This is then only a modem technically, not a router. All routers usually have 4 LAN ports or more, but given you said you only had 2, this is where the confusion starts. So, how many LAN ports do you have in total, even if you don't use them?

Comment: @Shahzad Rahim - The Internet connection is not needed, however If you have both computers online already then you are good to go. On each computer, open a command prompt and type **ipconfig**. This will show you the machines IP address, Subnet mask, and Gateway. The only thing you care about is IP address and subnet mask. The Subnet Mask is almost certainly **255.255.255.0**. This says that your machine IP addresses must both have the same first 3 octets such as *192.168.1.x* where *x* can be anything. From the command line of machine 1, *ping* machine 2 to confirm communication.

Comment: @LPChip I am terribly sorry, yes there are a total of 5 ports on the router and 4 of them are LAN, I said 2 ports thinking that might help explain the problem easier. Thank you for explaining the process. Lastly, I'd like to ask that--now that it's clear that I have a router, then a device like a router is capable of direct communication between 2 computers even without internet, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, definitely. A router is basically 3 devices in one: A modem, A switch and the router itself which translate traffic going between the modem and switch. All you want to use is the switch part in this case, so yes, you can definitely do this.

Comment: @LPChip Thank you very much!